# Convert XML String to IXMLDOMDocument2 JavaScript (ms Edge)

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing, microsoft-edge

I have a XML in string I need to convert it into IXMLDOMDocement2 in order to get the property `XMLDoc.selectNodes` in MS Edge

Please suggest what to do?

Comment: What have you tried? What have you found when researching your question?

Comment: `moXmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
moXmlDoc.async = "false";
moXmlDoc.preserveWhiteSpace = true;
moXmlDoc.loadXML(psXml);`  This Code works fine for IE but I not in Edge. //let psXML is my XML string

Comment: Edge still supports ActiveXObject? Colour me surprised! How does the above code fall short of your requirement

Comment: Edge does not support ActiveXObjects https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge

Comment: after returning moXMLDoc from the function I need to use like this `var TotalNodes = moXmlDoc.selectNodes("title")`

Comment: didn't think so - I take it the standard, cross browser [DomParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) doesn't work for you?

Comment: No, When I try to use `moXmlDoc.selectNodes("title");` It gives me an Error `Object doesn't support property or method 'selectNodes'`

Comment: You can use `evaluate` instead - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate

Comment: I restrict to use `selectNodes` that's why...

Comment: well you can't in Edge, or any other browser, except IE, but that's not really a browser, it's more like a back door into your computer

Comment: ok is there any way to append ActiveXObject in Edge

Comment: how about jquery XML stuff - https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: It returns same as DOM parser i.e `XMLDocument`, does't work for me

Comment: times change - so do browsers - you have to learn to work with what you get, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

If your website is not on intranet, add it to compatibility view. This way, the `responsexml` object returned will be of type `IXMLDOMDocement2` which will have methods to select nodes.

For us also, we were firing ajax request for which the output was XML string. After obtaining response, the `responsexml` object returned was of type `IXMLDOMDocement2` when the application was running on intranet (as intranet websites are automatically added to compatibility view by IE). However, during production, when the website moved to internet, the responsexml object returned was of type `XMLDocument` which does not have the method `selectNodes`. However, after adding the website to compatibility view, the issue got resolved. The returned `responsexml` object was automatically converted to `IXMLDOMDocement2`.